# Get location of user in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to get user's location. When I test the following code on my local computer it returns the correct position. Tried to change location with vpn and everything worked correctly too.

app.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
    r = requests.get(url)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    city = j['city']

    print(city)
```

But when I run my site with the same code on pythonanywhere it returns one incorrect city all the time, doesn't matter wherever I connect from. Does it return the location of the server instead? How can I get the correct location of each user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using your server IP for geolocation. When you visit that particular endpoint, it takes the client IP addresses, so when you deployed your app to Pythonanywhere - the client to that endpoint becomes the server.

When you were running the locally on your PC, you were requesting the API endpoint using your IP address - so if you switched to VPN, your IP address also changed.

In order to fix your current code, you need to pass the IP address of the client to `freegeoip.net/json` endpoint. Try this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/{}'.format(request.remote_addr)
    r = requests.get(url)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    city = j['city']

    print(city)
```

However, keep in mind that *this API endpoint is deprecated and will stop working on July 1st, 2018. For more information please visit: [https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme_)* - you may want to start using their new service - my solution is still applicable to their new API.

In some cases (like in Pythonanywhere) there might be a proxy server in front of your web app, rendering the `request.remote_addr` useless. In that case you should use the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Remember to use the correct value though. [Have a look at this good solution for more info](http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html).

Comment: I tried to do so but the problem is that request.remote_addr returns private ip address and the output of the request for such ip is empty

Comment: Try deploying it to the server and see if that works. If not, instead of using `request.remote_addr` try using `request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For')` - normally the http server should set the remote address for you, but in some cases it only puts the original IP address in that header. I didn't use Pythonanywhere, so I'm not sure which one it does.

Comment: thank you, request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For') worked!

Comment: Great, I'll edit the answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

use this code and thank me later!

```
from flask import *
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_ip():
    response = requests.get('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json').json()
    return response["ip"]

def get_location():
    ip_address = get_ip()
    response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{ip_address}/json/').json()
    location_data = {
        "ip": ip_address,
        "city": response.get("city"),
        "region": response.get("region"),
        "country": response.get("country_name")
    }
    return location_data
@app.route("/")
def home():
    data = get_location()
    return render_template("index.html",data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```