# how to get my current location using python

Tags: python, geolocation, location

how to get my current position using python

I tried to do it using @IP of my position but it gives me the location of my operator
I also tried to do it with web **scraping** it gives good result but the inconvenience is that the execution takes a long time to display the response (result)

please give me a solution or at least an idea since I have been looking for a solution for days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get location of user in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252156/get-location-of-user-in-flask)

Comment: You can always use  geopy module: https://pypi.org/project/geopy/

Comment: you need gps module for find the exact location like mobile ( google map on your cellphone )